# emacsclient "unknown command" when opening file

Tags: emacsclient, server, aquamacs

Whenever I try to open a file with emacsclient (and emacs is running, and the server is running, and the socket is there), I get this error message:

```
Marcins-MBP:docker-influxdb-grafana marcin$ emacsclient -s /Users/marcin/.emacs.d/server-sockets/server --alternate-editor="" influxdb.conf 
Waiting for Emacs...
-emacs-pid 3747
-error Unknown&_command:&_/Users/marcin/dev/thirdparty/docker&-influxdb&-grafana/influxdb.conf
```

What's up with that? How can I fix it?

I'm running aquamacs:

```
Aquamacs 3.3  GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0, NS appkit-1344.72 Version 10.10.2 (Build 14C109))
 of 2016-09-19 on 24a02dbf6b34ae061ef4df89f15bfbc5d3ed497e
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was using an old version of emacsclient. To fix this I had to do `Tools->Install Command Line Tools` as per this page: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AquamacsFAQ#toc25

I also had to use the versions installed in `/usr/local/bin`.